# Склонять название организации в кавычках или нет?

Tags: склонение, кавычки, названия

В письме в организацию, как правильно:

- Директору ООО "Сибирская Теплоэнергетическая компания"

или

- Директору ООО "Сибирской Теплоэнергетической компании"?

Answer (score 2):

Директору ООО "Сибирская Теплоэнергетическая компания".
Дело в том, что в этом варианте уже присутствует склонение, но оно скрыто в аббревиатуре. Если бы вы не использовали аббревиатуру "ООО", то вы бы написали "Директору Общества ..."
Таким образом, необходимый родительный падеж уже присутствует в этой фразе. Больше ничего склонять не нужно.

Comment: Ответ должен быть обоснован.

Comment: Да, я прошу прощения, просто не успел это сделать ночью, т.к. уже ложился спать и не было сил ответить подробно. Поэтому просто указал правильный вариант написания, так как допускал возможность того, что он нужен автору вопроса срочно.

Comment: Дополнить ответ никогда не поздно. Ставлю плюс.

Comment: @М_Г, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Директору ООО "Сибирская Теплоэнергетическая компания".

[Вопрос № 275993](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=275993)

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какое-нибудь правило в русском языке и/или, возможно, существует устоявшаяся практика склонения/несклонения наименований типа : "Городской Банк" (ОАО),  АКБ "Ромашкабанк" (ОАО) и т. п.
Правильно ли будет сказать (написать): устав "Городского Банка" (ОАО), правление АКБ "Ромашкабанка" (ОАО) и т. д.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка (Грамота.ру)

Название в кавычках может склоняться, если употребляется без родового слова: устав "Городского банка" (ОАО). Если родовое слово есть, название в кавычках не склоняется: правление АКБ "Ромашкабанк".